# SharePoint Database Hidden Form Tabs Displaying While Site Loads

Tags: permissions, form

I am trying to set up a user identified tab system in my SP forms. The problem is that when I set a user to not be shown a certain tab since they do not have permissions, it will display briefly while the initial page loads. Does anyone have this same issue or have an idea on how to make sure it doesn't show while the SP site loads for those without permissions?

Comment: Do it the opposite way, hide them all at first and only show the applicable ones after code execution.

Answer (score 0):

Audience Targeting would be your best bet if you're using a web part since it will only load the part if a user falls into specific groups.